# How to install the awus036h wifi adapter on ubuntu 15?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, hacking, alfa-wireless

I am running ubuntu on mac (new one). But when I attempt wifi penetrating on the device, it says "wifi penetration does not exist" I guess I need to install a patch file, as it says on the aircrack-ng page. (this is a legitimate wifi adapter) So can anyone be kind enough to find or give instructions on how to install the driver patch for the awus036h wifi adapter. PLEASE HELP thanks.